# Cannot make Powershell work for windows notification

Tags: powershell

I want to test notification in Powershell

I tried solution found on SO with https://gist.github.com/altrive/72594b8427b2fff16431
no error but no notification (I checked Background apps is on).

Then I tried this snippet (taken here https://michael-casey.com/2019/05/12/schedule-windows-notifications-with-powershell/) but I get error Exception calling "LoadXml" with "1" argument(s): "Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00CE558" and can't see how to fix it :

```
function test {
  
  $app = '{1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7}\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
 
  $Template = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastTemplateType]::ToastImageAndText01
   
  $ToastTemplate = ([Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::GetTemplateContent($Template).GetXml())
   
  $ToastTemplate = @"
  <toast launch="app-defined-string">
    <visual>
      <binding template="ToastGeneric">
        <text>Prevent Eye Strain</text>
        <text>Take a 20 second break</text>
      </binding>
    </visual>
  </toast>
"@
   
  $ToastXml = New-Object -TypeName Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
  $ToastXml.LoadXml($ToastTemplate.OuterXml)
   
  $notify = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier($app)
   
  $notify.Show($ToastXml)
   
  #source: https://gist.github.com/Windos/9aa6a684ac583e0d38a8fa68196bc2dc

}
```

Comment: Looks like you're forgetting the cast to `[xml]` on `$ToastTemplate`. Right now, it is just a string that doesn't have an `.OuterXml` property.

Comment: ..and if you follow the commented source link in the code, you wil find the correct function..